# Need assistance with cURL. Need to replace ajax call

Tags: php, ajax, curl

My client wants me to implement a page. On this page I made an API call using AJAX (as shown in code).

```
jQuery.ajax({
    url: endpoint,
    type: "POST",
    cache:false,
    data: {
            url:"link-rest/sweepstakes/claim",
            userId:193298,
            prizeRank:2,
            sweepStakeId:186
          },
    dataType: "json",
    headers: {
                Authorization:token
             },
    success: function(json){
            callback(json);
            },
    error: function(xhr, status, error){
            callback(errorHandle(2));
            }
});
```

But now he wants to use this page for SEO aswell. For that I have to make an API call in php. I have never worked with cURL before. And the examples on stackoverflow does not seem to work for me. I have Wamp Server installed and the php_curl extension has been activated. All services for wamp have also been restarted. This is what I tried to implement.

```
    $json_url = 'link-rest/sweepstakes/claim&userId=193298&prizeRank=2&sweepStakeId=186&Authorization=ams0TGpFek5EazBNekExTmprd01EYz1NVGt6TQ';

    $ch = curl_init($json_url);

    $options = array(
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array('Content-type: application/json'),
    );

    curl_setopt_array($ch, $options);

    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    var_dump(json_decode($result));
```

But all that is printed on my screen is "null". Can anyone please tell me what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: `cURL` won't work with a relative URL. You should use a fully qualified URL starting with something like `http://`.

Comment: Thanks to you and @Quentin. It was the problem that I was not giving an absolute URL. It worked perfectly fine once I got the URL right. Thanks once again. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The basic problem with the code is that you are using a relative URI and not an absolute one.

You also seem to be trying to provide a request encoded in JSON, but the Ajax appears to use standard form encoding and only expects JSON in the *response*

A more fundamental problem is that you are using cURL in the first place. `link-rest/sweepstakes/claim` is presumably handled via PHP, so you should refactor out the bits you want to call into a library and then call that library from the function you are writing. (While turning the page that handles the Ajax request into a simple View around it).